# Javascript - Create button dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a button dynamically using JavaScript and jQuery.

The code below is the final piece to a quiz and when the quiz is finished, it gives the results and states you have finished.  I would like to create a button dynamically using JS during this time which takes the user back to the home page (index.html).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function displayFinalSlide(){

    $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br><br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'</div>');

}//display final slide
```

Comment: Take a guess! You've come this far! That statement is adding a bit of HTML to the document. You want to add some more html; you need the markup to add a button/anchor.

Comment: Just add markup of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Like you are adding the html, Just add the anchor tag/Button as well

```
function displayFinalSlide(){

    $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br><br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'</div><a href="index.html">Index Page</a>'); // here in href you can give the path where you want to redirect to

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an invisible button that get you back to the home page:

```
<button id="finalButton" style="visibility:hidden">Go back</button>
```

and then in the function "displayFinalSlide()" above:

```
$('#finalButton').show();
```

I have omitted the jquery for the button click to get back to the main site.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the following  code in your code

```
function displayFinalSlide(){
$(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br>   <br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'</div>
<br/><button type="button" id="goback"> Home </button> '); } }); $("#goback").on("click",function(){window.location.assign('index.html');})
```